# Python: Remove URL from string, URL containing backslashes

Tags: python, regex, string, backslash

I need to remove the URLs (replace with only http) from a list of strings, but some URLs contain backslashes (\) in them. I searched online and found that \ is the escape character in Python. Stackoverflow answers I found did not help my task.

```
s = 'Future Of Education http://twitter.com/A6y2s9Hyys\xa0 Some right, some wrong.'
re.sub(r'http\S+', 'http', s)
```

The result I got is `Future Of Education http\xa0 Some right, some wrong.` instead of the one I want `Future Of Education http Some right, some wrong.` So I think the problem is that I can't find a way to deal with backslashes in strings?

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: I don't think that `\xa0` is part of the url, it's a unicode non-breaking space I believe

Comment: `http://\S+` will remove `\xa0` and `http://[^\s\\]+` will keep it.

Comment: @ctwheels I like that, you should post as an answer.

Comment: @chrisz you've already added an answer, you can just add that to your answer. I don't mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\xa0` is not a part of the URL, it is the unicode non-breaking space character.  You can update your regex to `http://\S+` to remove the `\xa0` from the end of your url:

```
s = 'Future Of Education http://twitter.com/A6y2s9Hyys\xa0 Some right, some wrong.'
print(re.sub(r'http://\S+', 'http', s))
```

Output:

```
Future Of Education http  Some right, some wrong.
```

Thanks to @ctwheels for the updated regex.

Comment: Thanks both for the answer chrisz and @ctwheels. It worked. I guess because \xa0 is a unicode space, I have to use the print() function to get the result?

Comment: No, you can store it in a string if you want, I was just putting the `print` to output the result.